# Python: How print a dictionary value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking for method to catch a value of this dictionary:

**The script:**

```
import wmi

raw_wql = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA \'Win32_USBHub\'"
c = wmi.WMI ()
watcher = c.watch_for(raw_wql=raw_wql)
while 1:
  usb = watcher ()
  print(usb)
```

**When i plug in a USB device. Output looks like:**

```
(wmi-py) C:\Users\USER\Source\wmi-py>py test.py

instance of Win32_USBHub
{
        Caption = "USB Composite Device";
        ConfigManagerErrorCode = 0;
        ConfigManagerUserConfig = FALSE;
        CreationClassName = "Win32_USBHub";
        Description = "USB Composite Device";
...
```

**i tested to use this:**

```
  x = usb.get("Description")
  print(x)
```

but it didint worked
I will apreciate for some suggestion

Comment: `x = usb.Description` or `getattr(usb, "Description", "")` if you want to not throw exceptions

Comment: Thanks Olvin Roght, worked too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. `usb` is not a dictionary

```
print(usb.Description)
```